# Groovy concatenate to dynamic query

Tags: sql, groovy, groovy-sql

In a little new to Groovy and am creating a piece of code which executes an sql query using a dynamic sql string.

```
def executeQuery(String csvQueryInList) {
  def result = sql.rows('SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable WHERE id IN (?,?)', ['1', '2'])
  return result
}
```

The above works but now I want to change this code to use the parameter csvQueryInList which is a CSV string.

Something like this....

```
  def sqlStr = 'SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable WHERE id IN ('
    def executeQuery(String queryInList) {

        def values = queryInList.tokenize(", ")
        values.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
            sqlStr << '?,'
        }
        sqlStr << ')'

        println "Executing generated query: $sqlStr"
        def result = sql.rows(sqlStr, values)
        return result
    }
```

But it doesn't quite work.

Can someone give me a hand to correct what I have wrong or suggest an even better way.

thanks

Comment: How many in the list? is it some thing dynamic?

Comment: It's a list of ids and can be 1 element long or 20 elements long. Ie it's dynamic.e.g 1,2,3,50.

Comment: Richie, thank you for clarifying. Would you please check if the below solution is helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there is issue while build the query with question marks.

Here you find the fixed one with couple of things to note

- Using method without passing `sqlStr` variable.
- Instead of `<<`, `+` could be used to *concatenate*.

Changed the method to pass `sqlStr` as well.

```
def sqlStr = 'SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable WHERE id IN ('
def listStr =  '1,2 , 3, 50'

def executeQuery(String queryInList, String query){
        //Get the list values from the list
        def values = queryInList.split(',')*.trim()
        //Build the question marks string
        def listOfQuestions = values?.inject([]){ list, it -> list << '?';list }.join(',')
        query += listOfQuestions + ')'
        println "Executing generated query: $query"
        def result = sql.rows(query, values)
        return result
}
executeQuery(listStr, sqlStr)
```

You can quickly try this <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/yWFoAn)</kbd> (only query building part) on-line.

Hope the above is useful.
​

Comment: brilliant thanks. I don't understand the inject part fully but rest assured I will be looking at this closely to understand it more.

Comment: It is basically building the list of questions and creating comma separated string. Appreciate if you can upvote the helpful answer.